# Approximating exponential generating function (EGF) from values of generating function (OGF)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I have a function that can evaluate ordinary generating function, and need to construct an approximation to the *exponential* generating function by using a few calls to the ordinary generating function. What functionality in Mathematica would make it easy?

A typical example is below. In this case I can EGF from OGF by using Laplace transform, but in general case this may be too expensive.

```
ogf = (159.774 - 1330.3 z + 5024.07 z^2 - 11359.6 z^3 + 17084.1 z^4 - 
   17943.2 z^5 + 13428.2 z^6 - 7159.87 z^7 + 2665.27 z^8 - 
   659.611 z^9 + 97.6646 z^10 - 6.55327 z^11)/(26.629 - 246.114 z + 
   1040.46 z^2 - 2660.31 z^3 + 4581.59 z^4 - 5598.57 z^5 + 
   4977.06 z^6 - 3243. z^7 + 1537.03 z^8 - 516.715 z^9 + 
   116.943 z^10 - 15.9963 z^11 + 1. z^12);
egfTrue = -InverseLaplaceTransform[ogf, z, -t];
Plot[egfTrue, {t, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Motivation: this would allow efficient powers of diagonal+rank1 matrix by relying on $(I-A)^t\approx \exp(-tA)$ which is related to EGF. Meanwhile corresponding OGF takes $O(d)$ time to compute at a single point using [trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654692/998) with Woodbury formula,

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this help:

Using [Heaviside  expansion formula](https://planetmath.org/heavisideformula) we can speed up to **20X**

```
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

ogf = (159.774 - 1330.3 z + 5024.07 z^2 - 11359.6 z^3 + 17084.1 z^4 - 
 17943.2 z^5 + 13428.2 z^6 - 7159.87 z^7 + 2665.27 z^8 - 
 659.611 z^9 + 97.6646 z^10 - 6.55327 z^11)/(26.629 - 246.114 z + 
 1040.46 z^2 - 2660.31 z^3 + 4581.59 z^4 - 5598.57 z^5 + 
 4977.06 z^6 - 3243. z^7 + 1537.03 z^8 - 516.715 z^9 + 
 116.943 z^10 - 15.9963 z^11 + 1. z^12);
ogfZ = Rationalize[ogf, 0];

INV = -Total[(Numerator[ogfZ]/D[Denominator[ogfZ], z]*Exp[-z*t] /. 
  NSolve[Denominator[ogfZ] == 0, z,WorkingPrecision -> 20])];(*Heaviside formula*)

egfTrue = -InverseLaplaceTransform[ogf, z, -t];

Plot[{egfTrue, INV}, {t, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}}]
Plot[egfTrue - INV // Re // Evaluate, {t, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Quiet
```

Comment: If we don't `Rationalize` and use `Solve` we can speed up to **70X.**

Comment: Neat! That has some curious resemblance to harder to implement [solution](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443030/7655) here -- write $e^{-x}$ as $1/p(x)$ for polynomial $p$, express it as sum of terms like $r(t y_i)=(1-t y_i)^{-1}$, putting OGF in place of $r$ then somehow gives EGF